# Junit - spring autowired fields are not injected

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have the following test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml" })
public class TestSanity {

   @Test
   public void testSanity() {

      new AnotherTestClass().simpleTest();
   }
}
```

Problem is AnotherTestClass autowire fields are all null (the spring context didnt load).  here is AnotherTestClass :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml" })
public class AnotherTestClass {

  @Autowired
  private PlayerService playerService;
  @Autowired
  private IPlayerSessionService playerSessionService;
  @Autowired
  private PlayerRepository playerRepository;


  @Test
  public void simpleTest() {

       ...
  }

  @Test
  public void complexAndLongTest() {

       ...
  }
```

Thing is both tests in  AnotherTestClass  runs perfectly when i test. 
How can i make the autowire fields to get injected?

Thanks

Comment: This `new AnotherTestClass()` is not a Spring managed bean.

Comment: This is not a duplicate since this question was raised in the context of Junit tests and not a simple spring configuration.

Comment: Is the question _How can i make the autowire fields to get injected?_. The answer would be to make it a Spring bean. As for the `@Test`s, that's a whole different question. The test class is handled by JUnit and the given `Runner`. Invoking a `@Test` annotated method is not the same as having JUnit invoke a `@Test` annotated method.

Comment: In other words, its not possible to invoke a test of one class from another. I see. Thanks

Comment: There might be a JUnit way to do it. But I don't think simply calling the method directly will achieve what you seem to want. If you'd like to edit your question to address that, I'll re-open. Currently, I feel the question is about why the fields are `null`.

Comment: OK, I will research for the right way, Thanks!

Comment: Yup, duplicate at this point. `AnotherTestClass` isn't managed, and it would be rather weird to inject a test case into another.